User without firstName and lastName working when migrating from KC23 to KC24
When I migrated from KC23 to KC24, Users without firstName and LastName are working and I am getting JWT Token for them
However if I install KC24 fresh, and I create user without firstName and LastName, I am not getting any jwt token and I got the error that "Account Not fully Setup". I do understand that keycloak has made it necessary to have firstName and lastName for user.
But my question is that when I am migrating from KC23 to KC24, why are the users working without firstName and lastName.
I checked the realm setting for both the versions and could not find any difference that could gave me a answer why it was working

Hi, same behaviour here, I noticed the firstName and lastName thing, but I also have users working without it. When I delete a user and recreate it, everything is ok. The error I get is from the account endpoint. I do not yet understand why it behaves this way.

faced the same, after KC24 you have to manually remove/disable firstName and lastName from Realm Settings->User Profile
